# COCOS 2D iPhone - Parsing variable between scenes and using in layer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have the code of calling a new scene with the variable:

```
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameScene sceneWithParam:item.tag]];
```

In GameScene.h

```
@interface GameScene : CCLayer {
}



+(id) sceneWithParam:(int)nvl;
@end
```

GameScene.m

```
+(id) sceneWithParam:(int)nvl
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    GameScene *layer = [GameScene node];

    [scene addChild: layer];

    return scene;

}


-(id) init
{

    if( (self=[super init] )) {



    }
    return self;
}
```

I can't use the variable `nil` inside `if( (self=[super init] )) {`
I have already tried to set a property `test`, and to `test = nvl; inside +(id) sceneWithParam:(int)nvl;` but it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's not possible to use dynamic parameters in static methods. If you want to create your object with parameters, you have to create an *init* method, receiving parameters you need. E.g.:

```
-(id) initWithYourParam:(id)param
{
    if ( (self=[self init]) ) {
        self.propertyParam = param;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: But how can I use the parameter in the layer (if( (self=[super init] )) {
) ?

Comment: Find the place, from where the code invokes your *init* method, I guess it's *[GameScene node];*. Now you haven't this method in your derived class, therefore it calls for parent's one. You need to implement *node* (or whatever method, which invokes your GameScene's *init*) in your GameScene class and make it call *initWithParam* instead of casual *init*

Comment: It works. I used [[GameScene alloc] initWithParam:nvl]. Thanks a lot.